# Calculate area of square, triangle and circle using both inheritance and function overloading, use shape as base class

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading, java.util.scanner

This is the code I wrote where base class is shape and there are 3 methods for the shape area using same keyword but different parameters, and in the main I have 1 class for each shape and which is derived from the shape class, but after running the main method I get a blank output with   exit code.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Shape {
    int b, h, s;
    double r;

    //triangle method
    void area(int base, int height) {
        int triArea = (base * height)/2;
        System.out.println("Area of Triangle = " + triArea);
    }

    //square method
    void area(int side) {
        int sqrArea = side * side;
        System.out.println("Area of Square = " + sqrArea);
    }

    //circle method
    void area(double radius) {
        double cirArea = Math.PI * radius * radius;
        System.out.println("Area of circle = " + cirArea);
    }
}

public class Area {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class Triangle extends Shape{
            void takeInput(){
                Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter base of Triangle: ");
                this.b = cin.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Enter height of Triangle: ");
                this.h = cin.nextInt();
                area(b, h);
            }
        }

        class Square extends Shape{
            void takeInput(){
                Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter side of Square: ");
                this.s = cin.nextInt();
                area(s);
            }
        }

        class Circle extends Shape{
            void takeInput(){
                Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Enter radius of Circle: ");
                this.r = cin.nextDouble();
                area(r);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why does your `Circle` can calculate the area of a triangle?

Comment: Your code does nothing because you don't do anyhting in your main method.

Comment: And note that your OO hierarchy isn't really helpful. A better way could be: make Shape abstract, and have an abstract method `protected double computeArea()` ... and a (non-abstract) method printArea() ... that calls the abstract one. Then your different subclasses have to implement computeArea differently. Conceptually, it is a really bad idea to put the 3 different computations into the base class.

Answer (score 0):

you just defined the Classes you also need to make a Objekt with those classes

```
Circle c = new Circle();
c.takeInput();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better to use an abstract method in `Shape`. Something like the following:

```
abstract class Shape {
    abstract void area(double... params);
}
```

and

```
public class Circle extends Shape {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Circle c = new Circle();
        double radius = 1;
        c.area(radius);
    }

    @Override
    void area(double... params) {
        if (params.length != 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected one argument as parameter (the radius).");
        }
        System.out.println("Circle area: " + (Math.PI * Math.pow(params[0], 2)));

    }

}
```